# Adding multiple SKUs to cart (with discount) in Shopify

Tags: shopify

We want to build a bundle product. For example we have SKU: AAA for $100 and SKU: BBB for $100. We want to create a product page where if you "add to cart" then SKU: AAA and SKU: BBB get added to cart with price of $150

Is this possible with Shopify? We can't use default discount code functionality to apply discount because we want the customer to be able to also use their own discount code (and shopify has 1 discount code per order limitation).

Answer (score 0):

YES.

You can use Shopify scripts and use a line item script which you can then write something that checks the cart/checkout items and IF the two items that are in the "bundle" exist then discount them by X amount. You can also write a custom message along with it to give feedback to the customer that the reason they got a discount was due to them been in a "bundle"

take a look at https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/apps/apps-by-shopify/script-editor/shopify-scripts for more information on Shopify scripts.

another good resource for example scripts can be found here

https://onlygrowth.com/blogs/posts/17-shopify-scripts-to-maximize-conversions

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if sku AAA and BBB are fixed.

Just simply create a product include AAA and BBB, compare at price set to $200, price set to $150.

Use order create webhook to check orders. When this pseudo product is sold, deduct the inventory of AAA and BBB.

Since this pseudo product doesn't have a discount applied, it can accept a discount code.

While it may have an oversell issue, it works most of the time.